AR(p) model in R not fitting data
I have a set of data that I am trying to model with a simple AR(p) model. I've run a Dickey Fuller test on unit root stationarity and reject the null.
However, when I run a simple ar command in R I seem to get a model with just an intercept. I have no idea why this is and hoping someone has some suggestions. Code below.
Data and R code included below:
data <- c(-2.93, -1.86, 0.45, -1.07, 5.92, 3.90, 1.28, -0.13, 1.33, 
          2.05, 17.69, -16.59, -3.84, -5.67, 4.76, -0.58, 1.06, 
          -0.63, 3.21, 1.06, -4.25, -6.24, -2.33, -6.64, 
          -4.56, -5.83, -1.99, 3.10, 7.82, 1.99, 4.42, -1.22, -7.52, 
          4.37, -3.24, -0.37, -2.77, -0.72, 0.10, -3.78, 1.35, -1.48, 
          -3.66, -1.87, -1.98, -2.39, -0.06, -0.16, 0.97, 3.79, 0.10, 
          -3.94, -2.00, 14.47, 5.29, -1.59, 6.86, -2.38, -9.99, -1.29, 
          -0.44, -4.45, 1.37, 6.36, 3.43, -0.60, 7.55, 5.34, -7.85, 
          8.52, 5.34, -13.36, 4.64, -0.61, 2.96, 4.90, 10.89, -7.19, 
          -2.16, -0.63, -6.03, -10.62, -7.78, -4.33, -3.55, -3.47, 
          1.64, -1.85, -2.88, 0.78, 12.39, -5.90)

time_series_data <- ts(data, start = c(2012, 5), frequency = 12)

ar_model <- ar(time_series_data, order.max = 3)

summary(ar_model)

residuals <- ar_model$resid

fitted_values <- time_series_data - residuals

print(fitted_values)

   Jan        Feb        Mar        Apr        May        Jun        Jul        Aug        Sep        Oct
2012                                             -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2013 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2014 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2015 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2016 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2017 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2018 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2019 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
            Nov        Dec
2012 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2013 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2014 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2015 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2016 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2017 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2018 -0.3021739 -0.3021739
2019 -0.3021739 -0.3021739 


I'm not familiar with the ar function but, with the arima function, you have to set the parameters that you want to use for the model. The ar function is probably similar so it defaults to just a mean most likely. I would look at the help for ar by doing ?ar at the R prompt.

Your model has minimal autocorrelation: try acf(time_series_data) to visualise this.  So perhaps your model thinks it cannot do justifiably do better than just projecting mean(time_series_data) as a constant.


I've run a Dickey Fuller test on unit root stationarity and reject the null.

Always carefully check what the null and alternative are!
Note that for the Dickey-Fuller test the null is that there is a unit root. Rejection implies stationarity.
See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dickey%E2%80%93Fuller_test first sentence:

... the Dickey–Fuller test tests the null hypothesis that a unit root is present ....

I used the adf.test function in tseries to check on your data (you didn't specify which package and function you used). The output does reject H0 at the 1% level and it quite clearly states in the output: "alternative hypothesis: stationary".
That is, the Augmented Dickey Fuller suggests that it doesn't have a unit root.
---
I recommend you plot the data. It tells the story.
You could also look at the ACF (which looks pretty consistent with white noise)
